# How to read dict data from file and covert to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I have following data in file. Getting error while I read and try convert to JSON.

**File(modes.txt) :**

```
{'status': True, 'mode': 'full'} {'status': False, 'mode': 'half'}
```

Code:

```
with open("modes.txt",'r') as f:
   ds = json.dumps(json.load(f))
```

Error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
>   line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Error is on expected line as file string in files are not double quoted. 
I could solve the problem replacing single-quote to double-quote.
What is good/elegant solution for this scenario?

Comment: The elegant solution is to correct the format of your file to proper JSON so it can be read properly.  The inelegant solution is using `eval()` to convert the strings into python dictionary objects and then pass it back, but it is definitely not recommended as `eval()` is not safe.  If you have control over how the file is generated the former is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Three issues with your source file's json format (tl;dr: it's not valid json)

1. it's a series of dicts, but they aren't in a list, they're bare
2. `True` is `true` in json, same for `False` which is `false`
3. As you noted, single vs double quotes.

You can get around these problems with the following:

```
import json

ds = list()


with open("modes.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        fixed_line = line.replace('\'', '"').replace("False", "false").replace("True", "true").strip()
        ds.append(json.loads(fixed_line))
```

This reads each line from your file, very roughly fixes it, and appends it to a list. End results is a list of dicts.

Please note this code is an example that's meant to demonstrate possible workarounds, don't actually use this in production. What if you modes.txt contains escaped doublequotes? Or the words `True` or `False` within strings?

Short answer: you should fix the input file to contain valid json.